# Magento: how to make canonical full/path/with/category/product-url?

Tags: magento, url, canonical-link

Question again. Sorry, cant find the answer :(
Magento 1.9.
I have several same pages:

```
1) domain/category/subcategory/product-page
2) domain/category/product-age
3) domain/product-page
```

When I **use canonical configuration** - I get **domain/product-page as canonical**.
But **I need FULL url domain/category/subcategory/product-page** canonical.
**Or 
404/301** from second and third type to first

Answer (score 0):

There's no great way to do this for many products (but there should be) as far I have found. If you have a limited number of products and can manually add the canonicals, then the following will work as an xml layout update on the specific products:

Custom Layout Update

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="addLinkRel">
<rel>canonical</rel>
<href>http://www.example.com/category/subcategory/productname.html</href>
</action>
</reference>
```

If you are trying to do this for 10k products, then it's probably not worth the time investment.